# Azure build pipeline publishUrl nesting indefinitely

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild

I just took over DevOps of a continuously integrated, continuously delivered Azure build pipeline, and all was going well… until today, when it's begun failing. I think the failures are due to an overlong file path on the web server.

Here is my error message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3000,5): Error : Copying file bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bootstrap\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bootstrap\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot failed. Could not find a part of the path 'obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bootstrap\fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

Evidently, it's just been dumping the project files into an ever-deeper rabbit hole of nested `bin\Release\Published` directories!

I checked what the resultant server path would be, and it amounts to 262 characters. My understanding is that this is longer than the Windows `MAX_PATH` value of 260, and I think that this is why my build is failing.

But I can't figure out how to stop that from happening.

My `.pubxml` file looks like this…

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>bin\Release\Published</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

…but I end up with a bottomless pit of `bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin\Release\Published\bin…`!!

I've updated the `.pubxml` file and checked it in successfully, but that seemed to have no effect. Here are my "Visual Studio build" pipeline details:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNO9U.png

`$(BuildPlatform)` = `any cpu` and `$(BuildConfiguration)` = `release`. I've tried supplying a different MSBuild argument for `/p:PublishUrl`, but that also didn't work.

How can I get this endless nesting to stop and my project to build!?

Thank you.

Comment: How's the result when you build the project locally? What kind of project do you use? Could you provide a sample project or detailed steps how to create a sample project to reproduce your issue? Also, share your build definition.

Comment: Any update to this issue?